# How to use html.render inside a thread?

Tags: python, html, multithreading, request, render

When trying to send a function to the stream that parses the page and then executes the html.render, an error occurs:
**Error: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (take_proxy_us_spys_one_thread)**
I started talking about a similar problem and realized that a friend [here](https://github.com/derlin/get-html/blob/master/blog/Rendering-HTML_a-journey.md) somehow managed to implement this. But I still get an error.

Here is my code which should be repeated all the time.
Help, please, to understand.

```
import urllib3
import requests
import time
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import threading
import fake_useragent

def take_proxy_us_spys_one(urls: list=[], header:dict = None,):
    for url in urls:
        try:
            url_first = 'https://spys.one'
            r = requests.get(url_first, headers=header)
            cookies = r.cookies
            session = HTMLSession()
            r = session.post(url,
                             data={'xx00': '','xpp': '5','xf1': '0','xf2': '0','xf3': '0','xf4': '0', 'xf5': '0'},
                             headers=header,
                             cookies=cookies)
            r.html.render(reload=False,)
            print(str(r))
        except Exception as exc:
            print("Error: " + str(exc))

def take_proxy_us_spys_one_thread(event, sleeptime= 60, urls=[], lock = None):
    while event.is_set():
        try:
            user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
            header = {'User-Agent': user}
            lock.acquire() if lock!=None else None
            proxies_1 = take_proxy_us_spys_one(urls=urls, header=header)
            lock.release() if lock != None else None
            time.sleep(sleeptime)
        except Exception as exc:
            print("Error: " + str(exc))
            time.sleep(sleeptime)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_in_thread = True
    urllib3.disable_warnings()

    urls_spys_one = [
        'https://spys.one/free-proxy-list/ALL/'
    ]

    lock = threading.Lock()
    event = threading.Event()
    event.set()

    t2 = threading.Thread(target=take_proxy_us_spys_one_thread, args=(event, 10, urls_spys_one, lock),).start()
```

I tried to implement the mechanism [from here](https://github.com/derlin/get-html/blob/master/blog/Rendering-HTML_a-journey.md).

Comment: Im having the same issue, any solutions?

Comment: There is no implementation option in streams. It is worth using other mechanisms.