# Speed up python web-scraping

Tags: python, optimization

I am writing this python script to scrap a website for collecting information. After I entered the date and the no. of game on that date, this script will help me to go to the site and scrap a specific table and save each game into a CSV file. There are 12 rows of the tables, so that's why you see I have hardcoded it in the for loop.

The script works but I would like to seek for the suggestion from you experts to optimize and speed up the script. I thought using concurrent would speed up but it doesn't give a obvious improvement.

It would be great if anyone can help. At the moment, this script would take 20-30 seconds to complete for one date scrap.

Thank you very much for your time!

```
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests_cache

session = HTMLSession()
requests_cache.install_cache(expire_after=3600)

game_date = input("Please input the date of the game that you want to scrap (in YYYY/MM/DD): ")
game_no = int(input("Please input how many game on that date: "))

def split_list(big_list, chunk_size):
    return [big_list[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(big_list), chunk_size)]

def get_game_result(game):
    print(f"Processing game {game}")
    url = f"https://example.com{game_date}&{game}"  <<< example link
    response = session.get(url)
    response.html.render(sleep=5, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1)
    row_body = response.html.xpath(f"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]")

    final_list = []
    for i in range(2, 14):
        for item in row_body:
            item_table = item.text.split("\n")
            final_list.append(item_table)
            row_body = response.html.xpath(f"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]")
        i += 1

    df = pd.DataFrame(final_list)
    df.to_csv(f"game_{game}.csv", index=False, header=False)
    print(f"Finished processing game {game}")

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(get_game_result, game) for game in range(1, game_no + 1)]
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        f.result()
```

Comment: you are really not utilizing threads here, the executor is sitting idle. pls go through some tutorials - a good [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU). you need each game to be handled in one thread so loop instance processing is via threads. pls let us know if that still did not help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
First of all, please forgive me I am still in beginner phase and learning Python. So, I am thinking about trying to leverage multi-threading but seem this is pretty hard for me at this stage. So, I tried my best to modify the code after I watched the video, but it pop this error - 
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3'.

It would be great you can help, thanks!

Comment: that awesome! you have been blocked by `HTMLSession` in threading similar to [HTMLSession with threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829910/how-to-use-html-render-inside-a-thread), this needs some more research will get back to you.

Comment: I did abit of resarch, just wondering if this is related to the GIL (the Global Interpreter Lock)?

Comment: it may be, pls refer [issues](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues) on this module

Comment: example code [threading_with_html_session](https://github.com/simpleappdesigner/programs/blob/main/htmlsessionthreads.py), pls adjust as per needs. if you can provide `game_date` and `game_no` , then can adjust the code.